# Влияют ли разделы на ssd на срок его службы?

Tags: ssd

Если ssd разделить на несколько разделов, на которых будут находиться файлы, перезаписываемые с разной частотой, то повлияет ли это отрицательно на сроке службы ssd?

Например:

- windows - часть файлов никогда не меняется, но сам раздел используется активно
- pagefile - используется почти постоянно
- ещё система - предполагается использовать редко
- линуквовый своп - используется крайне редко, в том числе из-за редкого использования самого линукса

Насколько я представляю, контроллер ssd сам распределяет по нему данные и при этом разделы никак не учитываются, но всё равно смущает то, что некоторые файлы могут лежать почти вечно, т. е. часть ячеек будет считаться занятыми и не будут перезаписываться?

А может, надо просто дефрагментацию иногда запускать, чтобы оно переместилось? В таком случае, что делать с линуксовым свопом? Он считается свободным или занятым? Дефрагментация к нему, очевидно, неприменима.

Comment: Вроде бы современные ОС понимают, когда их ставят на SSD и в этом случае размещают своп-файл на обычном диске. Ну, или обходятся без своп-файла, если в системе нет обычного диска. А так-то ресурс записи даже для лучших флешек всего 1 миллион, так что любой своп-файл запилит флешку очень быстро.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, а какой смысл вообще использовать ssd, если самые тормоза, вызываемые обращениями к файлу подкачки останутся на месте? Какое-то оно тогда бесполезное получается.

Comment: Да, всё ставится, как и на HDD. Только вместо дефрагментации делается операция TRIM, это когда файловая система указывает SSD накопителю сектора находящиеся в списке свободных, тем самым позволяя их стирать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реальное расположение сектора на SSD постоянно меняется, меняется почти каждый раз когда вы переписываете сектор, но вы этого не замечаете, на SSD расположены специальные таблицы переадресации, которые отображают логический номер сектора в физический, а пользователь имеет дело с логическими секторами.

Это делается, чтобы равномерно распределять износ секторов при записи, а также по той причине, что микросхемы памяти на которых строятся SSD обычно могут стирать информацию только большими порциями от 4 до 64 килобайт, а записывать могут небольшими секторами по 256 байт.

Итого: на срок эксплуатации SSD отрицательно влияет только количество записей, причём не важно в какое место

Comment: _"меняется почти каждый раз когда вы переписываете сектор"_ - так а что с лежащими неизменяющимися данными будет? Получается, у этих секторов будет всего одна перезапись? Т. е. записываемое распределяется по оставшимся секторам, увеличивая число перезаписи тех, а эти будут лежать неизменные с одной? И я момент про стирание вообще не понял. Чем стирание отличается от записи?

Comment: Да, неизменные сектора так и останутся с одной перезаписью. Стирание заполняет страницу т. е. несколько секторов единицами, а запись может только переводить единицы в нули.

Comment: А что сделать, чтобы их иногда двигали?

Comment: А зачем их двигать? Чтобы износ равномернее был?

Comment: Да, для равномерности.

Comment: В конце концов такие сектора должны быть перемещены из-за сборки мусора, наступит момент, когда этот сектор будет на странице единственный в работе, тогда его переместят, чтобы он не мешал стереть страницу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88576/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-pavel-gridin).

Answer (score 1):

> @pepsicoca1, а какой смысл вообще использовать ssd, если самые
>   тормоза, вызываемые обращениями к файлу подкачки останутся на месте?
>   Какое-то оно тогда бесполезное получается. – Qwertiy♦

Смысл в том, что оверлеи (которые в винде выполнены в виде dll) быстрее читаются с SSD, и за счет этого система работает быстрее. В сети есть много обзоров, что и как надо сделать, чтобы система правильно работала с SSD. Вот несколько ссылок:

https://ustanovkaos.ru/sborka/nastroyka-ssd-pod-windows-10.html
https://pcpro100.info/ustanovka-windows-10-na-ssd/

То есть если Вы файл подкачки расположили на HDD, а систему и установленные программы расположили на SSD, то файл подкачки у Вас работает не хуже, чем раньше. Зато dll читаются с SSD-диска гораздо быстрее. Если, к примеру, Вы игроман, то это значит, что новые сцены в Вашей любимой стрелялке будут загружаться мгновенно на самых высоких уровнях разрешения.

Вот обзор на эту тему:

http://onoutbukax.ru/rol-ssd-diska-v-igrah-i-naskolko-on-vazhen/

Тут, правда, автор рекомендует и файл подкачки располагать на SSD, но это утверждение уже на его совести. Судя по тому, что сама Микрософт в вин-10 автоматом предлагает расположить файл подкачки все-таки на HDD, автор, скорее всего, погорячился. Ну, или у него много денег, и он может себе позволить часто менять SSD-диск.

Другие приложения тоже ускорятся. Если Вы не игроман, а программист-разработчик, то следует ожидать ускорения работы Вашего любимого IDE и ускорения трансляции.

UPD1:

Там, по ссылкам написано, что не только файл подкачки рекомендуется отключить на SSD. Рекомендуется перенести папку Temp на HDD, рекомендуется отключить автоматическую дефрагментацию, индексацию и прочие системные сервисы, которые могут быстро запилить SSD-диск. В приведенных ссылках речь идет о винде. С Линуксом я работал мало, но думаю, что современные продвинутые дистрибутивы Линукса (типа Убунты) тоже поддерживают SSD-диски в том смысле, что предлагают вынести часто записываемые файлы на HDD. Не современные дистрибутивы Линукса скорее всего придется настраивать вручную.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88578/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-pepsicoca1).

Comment: Файл подкачки на ssd, на него же пишется довольно объёмное видео с экрана, за это время износ 7% (т. е. осталось 93%), объём ssd - 1 TB. Загрузки и документы на hdd.